# Should error notifications work in Forum module in EE 1.6.9?

Tags: forum

We have a legacy site running EE 1.6.9, and the Forum module 2.1.0.  (Upgrading is not an option due to changes needed in dozens of templates.)

We have just noticed that when running the forum through EE templates, we are no longer getting the Post Submission validation error messages.  We do get them when running just through the forum templates.

We've also tried changing the theme from our custom one, to all of the other default themes, and see the same issue.

Does anyone else remember having this issue, or know of a fix?   I can't even seem to find the EE 1.x bug tracker any longer.

Answer (score 1):

This **[EE forum post](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/214903/)** may detail the solutions.

Are you saving templates as files?

Is there was a template in the site template folder called ‘forums’ or whatever you are using for your forum template name?

If there is, you should get your errors back if you remove or rename that template. It's hijacking the errors apparently.

Comment: - Tx, but that post is not relevant, and a much newer version of EE / Forum

- Yes,  saving templates as files, but this should work, and still provide the error messages


- I have the forum short name as a template group,  with its index holding the forum tag. This should not prevent errors


- Nothing is hijacking the errors, this is just a bug. Was wondering if anyone had a fix,  but thanks none the less!

Comment: Humor me a little so I know you checked the right thing... What is the name of the template group your forum tag is in? Do you have a template with that same name in your main template group? The one where your homepage template is? That combo was the issue is that forum post.

Comment: This is another issue.  But here you go: the forum tag is in a Template Group named 'creator_forum', and there isn't a template by the same name in the main (site root) template group.

Comment: Got it. I don't have an EE2 site with a forum on it so can't test on my end for you unfortunately.